When is onAuthStateChanged() fired in a Netxjs app?
I have the following useEffect hook in the root page.tsx file of a nextjs app. On my /SignIn page.tsx I have implemented Google as a login provider using FirebaseAuth. If I now log in with signInWithPopup, I expect the onAuthStateChanged() method in the hook to be called immediately afterwards - but it doesn't. Or am I doing something wrong?
root page.tsx:
useEffect(() => {
 const unSub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
     fetchUserInfo(user?.uid as any);
 });

 return () => {
   unSub();
 };
}, [fetchUserInfo]);

SignIn page.tsx:
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
setLoading(true);

signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then(async (result) => {
    const user = result.user;
   ...
 }


does auth have a correct value when it executes this line signInWithPopup(auth, provider)? would be nice if you could post full code of signin/page.tsx

It should trigger immediately after successful signin.  How do you know yours is not?  I don't see any logs or clear indication that 1) the observer was added or 2) that it definitely runs. For all we know, maybe the observer just wasn't actually added, or maybe fetchUserInfo just isn't doing what's expected of it.

I will also point out that the observer will not fire on a page that isn't currently loaded.  If the user navigated away from that page, the observer is simply gone.

As Doug said in his comment...

the observer will not fire on a page that isn't currently loaded. If the user navigated away from that page, the observer is simply gone.

You should put onAuthStateChanged() in your root layout.tsx, not your root page.

Not in a Nextjs application I think. Since layout does not run on the client side, “use client”. And I register the onAuthStateChanged() within a useEffect
